# How to log source error in elmah mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I want to log source error in error page of my asp.net mvc application in the image.
[image]

Elmah just log stack trace.

Is there any config that i should set? How?

Comment: What source are you talking about? The File, Line number etc.?

Comment: first yellow area in the image titled Source Error:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH doesn't log this, since this is an UI feature of the yellow screen of death. The information in Source Error, is basically the same as in the stack trace. As what I can see, [ErrorFormatter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/ErrorFormatter.cs) is used to generate this.